# Packaged Electron app does not launch when run from Dock but works fine when run from Terminal

Tags: macos, electron, child-process, electron-builder

So this is a bit of an odd one. I have an Electron app packaged using `electron-builder`. The app attempts to spawn a Java process using `child_process.spawn()` and uses `minimal-request-promise` to poll every 500ms to see if the local API has started.

When I run the app from Terminal with 
`open myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp` it works fine. I see console output as the `SpringBoot` app starts and once it's initialised the `BrowserWindow` pops up.

However, if I just run `myApp.app` (from Dock, Spotlight, Terminal, whatever), the icon pops up in the Dock but nothing happens, even after 10 minutes left alone.

I'm assuming this is because there's an error spawning the process (and since we're not running the executable we don't get the Terminal output to say so.. grr).

What would be the best way to try and debug this? I can't work out why it'd work one way and not the other unless it's a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that my API was throwing exceptions because the database file it was trying to create was inside the packaged app. Changed the location and now everything works fine.

For anyone in a similar position, you can use [`electron-log`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-log) to log to a file rather than console (since you don't have console from a `.app` file).